# Error: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value in Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a cloud function that will update some data when an action triggers the cloud function.

## My code is:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.UpdateLocations = functions.firestore.document("users/{userID}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const userEmail = change.after.data().email;
    const prevLocation = change.before.data().userLocation;
    const currentLocation = change.after.data().userLocation;

    if (prevLocation === currentLocation) return 0;

    // Here I want to get this user's patients or relatives list. Then store emails in a List.
    // Then search emails, and get patients or relatives list.
    // With my email, update my current location in patients or relatives list.

    if (change.after.data().userType.toString() === "Patient") {
        const userLocation = change.after.data().userLocation;
        const relatives = change.after.data().relatives;
        const relativeEmails = relatives.map(r => r["email"]);

        console.log("Relatives' email : " + relativeEmails);
        console.log("User's Current Location: " + userLocation);

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(relativeEmails, async relativeEmail => {
            console.log("Relative email : " + relativeEmail);
            const [relative] = await db.collection("users").doc(relativeEmail.toString()).get();

            const patients = relative.data().patients;

            console.log("Inside relativeEmails.foreach, relative:" + relative.email);

            [...patients].foreach((patient, index) => {
                console.log("Inside patients.foreach, patient : " + patient + ", and his email : " + patient["email"]);

                if (patient["email"] === userEmail) {
                    console.log("Inside if statement");
                    return relative.data().patients[index].set({
                        "userLocation": currentLocation
                    });
                }
                console.log("Outside if statement");

            });
        });


    }


});
```

---

## Error:

```error
i  functions: Beginning execution of "UpdateLocations"
>  Relatives' email : relativeaccount@gmail.com
>  User's Current Location: 12.22422,31.3131
>  Relative email : relativeaccount@gmail.com
>  Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
i  functions: Finished "UpdateLocations" in ~1s
>  Inside relativeEmails.foreach, relative:undefined
>  (node:1160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: (intermediate value).foreach is not a function
>      at Array.forEach.call (D:\Firebase Projects\Harmony-Firebase\functions\index.js:34:27)
>      at <anonymous>
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
>  (node:1160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>  (node:1160) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

---

How can I solve this problem? It also doesn't recognize `relative.email`.

*Here is my sample data structure, if it help*

[image]

---

Only difference between `Patient` and `Relative` user type is that `Patient` has `relatives` list, and `Relative` has `patients` list. That is why I am not giving both of them.

***Note:*** I am also not sure about `[...patient].foreach`. I would use it like `Array.prototype.forEach.call()`, but I don't know how I can get `index` in it.

Comment: Your code isn't returning a promise that resovles when all the async work is complete, which is a requirement for Cloud Functions.  The return statement in the function you pass to forEach isn't doing that - it's just returning from that inner function and not the outer function that you pass to onCall.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am new in cloud functions and javascript. That's why I am not sure I understood your sugestion. If you would give an example as answer of the questions, It was wonderful. Then I can verify it.